# Convert IP-ranges to singel IP addresses BASH

Tags: bash

Have been searching and tried diffrent ways.
As for now i have code that is like this:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prbutler/EZProxy_IP_Blacklist/master/EZProxy_IP_Blacklist_RejectIP.txt | grep "RejectIP " | awk '{print $2}'  >> EZProxyIP_ALL.txt
cat EZProxyIP_ALL.txt | grep "-" | sed -r 's/-/ /g' >> EZProxy_Range.txt
cat EZProxyIP_ALL.txt | grep -v "-" >> EZProxyIP.txt
rm EZProxyIP_ALL.txt
```

Now this creates two text files, one with all single addresses, and one with the ranges of ip's.
I'm using sed so that the text file EZProxy_Range.txt looks like this:

```
5.8.44.0 5.8.46.255
```

Now i'm trying to make the script to list all the ip addresses like this:

```
5.8.44.0
5.8.44.1
And so on...
```

But i can't figure it out, how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE perl using the [Net::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP) :

For input lines such (`-` delimited range, e.g. you don't need your `sed -r 's/-/ /g'`

```
10.10.10.1 - 10.10.10.5
10.11.11.250 - 10.11.12.4
```

using

```
perl -MNet::IP -nlE '$i=Net::IP->new($_);while($i){say $i++->ip()}'
```

produces:

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.3
10.10.10.4
10.10.10.5
10.11.11.250
10.11.11.251
10.11.11.252
10.11.11.253
10.11.11.254
10.11.11.255
10.11.12.0
10.11.12.1
10.11.12.2
10.11.12.3
10.11.12.4
```

more readable

```
perl -MNet::IP -nlE '
    $i = Net::IP->new( $_ ); 
    while( $i ) {
        say $i++->ip()
    }'
```

Comment: @FredrikDiffeSandström yw & enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script with nested loops to solve this for you in a pure bash way.

gen_ip.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

START=$1
END=$2

IFS='.' 
read -r -a SIP <<< "$START"
read -r -a EIP <<< "$END"

for (( a = ${SIP[0]} ; a <= ${EIP[0]} ; a++)); do
for (( b = ${SIP[1]} ; b <= ${EIP[1]} ; b++)); do
for (( c = ${SIP[2]} ; c <= ${EIP[2]} ; c++)); do
for (( d = ${SIP[3]} ; d <= ${EIP[3]} ; d++)); do
    echo "$a:$b:$c:$d"
done
done
done
done
```

Generates

```
% sh gen_ip.sh 5.8.44.0 5.8.46.255
5:8:44:0
5:8:44:1
5:8:44:2
...
...
5:8:46:253
5:8:46:254
5:8:46:255
```